# Is this translation accurate?

Tags: translation

I just received a message from the Italian embassy (*i am Italian but was born and live in Greece, and do not speak Italian*), which i was expecting, to go pick my new passport, for which i had applied a week ago.

but the translation of the message seems to talk about my daughter (*no passport application for her*)

> il  passaporto di sua figlia e’ pronto

translation

> your daughter's passport is ready

Is the translation accurate, or does it translate some other way as well ?

---

If the translation is accurate, how would i reply with

> Hopefully, the passport is for me and not my daughter.

Comment: Welcome Gabriele to Italian SE! The Italian message has been translated correctly and cannot be misunderstood: the passport is ready for your daughter, but there's no news about yours one. So, to provide a valid answer, I need you to tell us if your daughter has something to do with it. There are *two* cases: **1)** Someone has misunderstood the passport was precisely for you; **2)** There were multiple passports to complete, then yours is not the only one and will soon be processed.

Comment: Well, i do have a daughter but there is no application for her. I am assuming it might be a confusion because i also updated my civil status (and notified them about my daughters existence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments: the translation of the Italian message is correct and there was an evident misunderstanding between you and the Italian embassy...

You can kindly reply something like:

> Mi scusi, ci dev'essere stato un malinteso... il passaporto sarebbe dovuto spettare a me, il motivo è dovuto al cambio del mio stato civile. Ci sarebbe modo di porvi rimedio?

That in English means:

> Excuse me, there must have been a misunderstanding... the passport should have belonged to me, the reason is due to the update of my marital status. Would there be any way to solve this issue?

Comment: In any case, the OP should be able to continue the conversation in English or Greek, without need to rely on our translations. Surely somebody working at an embassy must be able to speak all three languages. Probably they defaulted to Italian because OP's name looks very Italian, but an answer in a different language should not be a problem.